# JavaScript manage object properties with duplicate property names

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript object:

```
    var list = {
        ListId: '',
        Items: {}
    };
```

What I want to do is to be able to add dynamic properties to `Items` property object. User can define properties with the same name but the logic should check if the property exists and if yes create same property name by adding a suffix or prefix (generated) but user will still see same property name.

Example:

```
    var list = {
        ListId: '',
        Items: {
              Name :{
                   Value: 'Some Value',
                   DisplayName: "Name"   
              },
              Name1 :{
                   Value: 'Some Other Value',
                   DisplayName: "Name"   
              },
              Name2 :{
                   Value: 'Some Third Value',
                   DisplayName: "Name"   
              }
        }
    };
```

How can I manage this object properties?

I managed to figure out how to add properties if they don't exist:

```
   function addProperty(name) {
        if (!list.Items.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            list.Items[name] = '';
        }
    };
```

Comment: Is it an option to use array of objects? Like Items: [{Name: {Value: "Some Value" }}]?

Comment: `"but user will still see same property name."` Could you please clarify?

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen was going to add the same comment " user will still see" is unclear

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen: The actual property name is also an object. If the same property exists generate new name and that object will have 2 properties: Value and DisplayName ... where DisplayName can be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your new property is an object, not a blank string, so that at least should have been

```
function addProperty(name) {
    if (!list.Items.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        list.Items[name] = {};
    }
};
```

Furthermore, you have all the methods right there you need, just create an `else` part and numerically increment the `name` until you find one that does not exist:

```
function addProperty(name) {
    if (!list.Items.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        list.Items[name] = {};
    }
    else{
       var i = 1;
       while(list.Items.hasOwnProperty(name + i)){
           i++;  
       }
       list.Items[name + i] = {};
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the wanted name is a keys of the item property. If `true`, then it could be used.

```js
function checkIsFree(item) {
    return !(item in list.Items);
}

var list = { ListId: '', Items: { Name: { Value: 'Some Value', DisplayName: "Name" }, Name1: { Value: 'Some Other Value', DisplayName: "Name" }, Name2: { Value: 'Some Third Value', DisplayName: "Name" } } };

document.write(checkIsFree('Name5') + '<br>'); // true
document.write(checkIsFree('Name2') + '<br>'); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   var indexes = {};
   function addProperty(name, value) {
        if (!list.Items.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            list.Items[name] = value;
        } else {
            indexes[name] = indexes[name]+1 || 1;
            list.Items[name + indexes[name]] = value;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Code below shall perform desired action:

```
function addProperty(obj, name) {
    if (!obj.Items.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      obj.Items[name] = '';
      return true
    }
    return false
};

function addIndexedProperty(obj, name){
  var i = 1;
  var originName = name;
  while (!addProperty(obj, name)){
    name = originName + i;
    i++;
  }
  return obj
}

var list = {
  ListId: '',
  Items: {} 
};

addIndexedProperty(list, 'Name');
addIndexedProperty(list, 'Name');
addIndexedProperty(list, 'Name');
console.log(list['Items']); // Object {Name: "", Name1: "", Name2: ""}
```

**Good Luck !**

Comment: this will add name like `Name1234` instead of `Name4`

Comment: Add a 3rd test, it'll be `Name12`

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion to add suffix. Use `hasOwnProperty` to find if a key exists.

**Algorithm**

1. Function takes name,value and length as arguments. Length initially is 0.
2. When the supplied key already exists, it increments the length and checks if the (name+length) key exists.

   - If it does not exist, it recursively calls itself with the arguments (name+length,value,0). This will add the key to the list.
   - If the (name+length) key does not exist, the length is incremented and the the function is called with (name,value,length). This goes on.

If the key does not exist, it is simply added.

```js
var list = {
  ListId: '',
  Items: {
    Name: {
      Value: 'Some Value',
      DisplayName: "Name"
    },
    Name1: {
      Value: 'Some Other Value',
      DisplayName: "Name"
    },
    Name2: {
      Value: 'Some Third Value',
      DisplayName: "Name"
    }
  }
};


function addProperty(name, value, length = 0) {
  if (list.Items.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    length++;
    if (list.Items.hasOwnProperty(name + length)) {
      return addProperty(name, value, length);
    } else {
      return addProperty(name + length, value, 0);
    }
  } else {
    return list.Items[name] = value;
  }
};
addProperty('this_argument_does_not_exist_yet', 'val');

addProperty('Name', 'val');

addProperty('Name', 'val');

addProperty('Name', 'val');
addProperty('Name1', 'val');


console.log(list);

document.getElementById('mypre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(list,null,2);
```

```html
<pre id="mypre"></pre>
```